# I am trying to validate the user input. But if i entered an invalid character the program goes to an infinite loop

Tags: c, validation, input, scanf, infinite-loop

I am trying validate the user input.
In case of an invalid input i am trying to ask the user to reinsert a correct numeric(double) value.

The program is not working, its going to an infinite loop.

Could you please give me any suggestion how can i do this ?
Thanks.!!

int main() {

```
double t; /* Input from user */

int  check;
check = 0;

/* This loop is use to validate the user input.                 *
 * For example: If the user insert a character value "x".       *
 * i am trying to ask the user to insert a valid numeric value. */

while (check == 0)
{
    printf("Insert the value: ");
    if (scanf(" %lf", &t) == 1) {
        check = 1;          /* Everythink okay. No loop needed */
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed to read double. ");
        check = 0;          /* loop aganin to read the value */
        fflush( stdout );
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

expected results:
$ ./a.out 
Insert the value: X 
Failed to read double. 
Insert the value: 5 

 
actual results : 
$ ./a.out 
Insert the value: X 
Insert the value: Failed to read double. Insert the value: Failed to read double.  ( loop )...

Comment: This `X` is left in the input stream. You need to remove it. Consider using `fgets` and parsing it (with `sscanf` for example) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if i entered an invalid character the program goes to an infinite loop... if i entered an invalid character the program goes to an infinite loop

OP's code is simply re-attempting to convert the same failed data endlessly.

When `scanf(" %lf", &t) == 0`, non-numeric input remains in `stdin` and needs to be removed. [@Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54296060/i-am-trying-to-validate-the-user-input-but-if-i-entered-an-invalid-character-th/54296447#comment95412490_54296060).

```
int conversion_count = 0;
while (conversion_count == 0) {
  printf("Insert the value: ");
  // Note: lead space not needed. "%lf" itself consumes leading space.
  // if (scanf(" %lf", &t) == 1) {  
  conversion_count = scanf("%lf", &t); 

  // conversion_count is 1, 0 or EOF
  if (conversion_count == 0) {
    printf("Failed to read double.\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    int ch;
    // consume and discard characters until the end of the line.
    while ( ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF)) {
      ; 
    }
    if (ch == EOF) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

if (conversion_count == 1) {
  printf("Read %g\n", t);
}  else {
  printf("End-of-file or input error\n");
}
```

Comment: @Protick Usually better to remove the entire non-numeric line than just 1 character.  OTOH, you could post your solution as an answer here too.